# NSDictionary isn't responding to objectForKey and valueForKey

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dictionary, nsdictionary

I have the following

```
// this code is inside cellForRowAtIndexPath for a TableViewController

id answer = [self.answers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([answer respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey)]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [answer valueForKey:@"answer_id"];
} else {
    // I'm ending up here, instead of the cell.textLabel being set
    [NSException raise:@"Answer is of invalid class" format:@"It should be able to respond to valueForKey, class: %@", [answer class]];
}
```

where `self.answers` is set to

```
// the question that gets passed here is a parsed single object 
// from the `/questions` path
- (NSArray *)answersForQuestion:(NSDictionary *)question {
    NSString *contents = [self loadContentsForPath:[question valueForKey:@"question_answers_url"]];
valueForKey:@"question_answers_url"]];
    NSDictionary *data = [contents JSONValue];
    NSArray *answers = [data valueForKey:@"answers"];
    return answers;
}

- (NSString *)loadContentsForPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSString *wholeURL = [@"http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1" stringByAppendingString:path];    
    return [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:wholeURL] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
}
```

I'm doing exactly the same thing for loading questions which works just fine, but it seems
to fail on answers when I try to do `[answers valueForKey:@"answer_id"]`.

I don't think this is a problem with the JSON parser, because it works fine for the `/questions` data.

When the debugger stops on the exception and when I try to right click -> Print Description on `answers`, I get

```
Printing description of answer:
<CFBasicHash 0x6ec1ec0 [0x1474b38]>{type = mutable dict, count = 13,
entries =>
    1 : <CFString 0x6ec57d0 [0x1474b38]>{contents = "down_vote_count"} = <CFNumber 0x6e1dc00 [0x1474b38]>{value = +0, type = kCFNumberSInt32Type}
    2 : <CFString 0x6ec4ee0 [0x1474b38]>{contents = "last_activity_date"} = <CFNumber 0x6ec5780 [0x1474b38]>{value = +1326379080, type = kCFNumberSInt64Type}
    3 : <CFString 0x6ec44b0 [0x1474b38]>{contents = "community_owned"} = <CFBoolean 0x1474f68 [0x1474b38]>{value = false}
...
```

which to me seems like a regular hash. I tried both `objectForKey` and `valueForKey` and neither of them work, i.e.

```
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b2a330'
```

when I do just

```
cell.textLabel.text = [answer objectForKey:@"answer_id"];
```

Comment: Did you actually read the exception description? It tells you what the problem is *right there*.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan Yes but I didn't know that I can't assing NSNumber to a NSString, as I mainly do Ruby where this is completely ok. Now it just seems like a really dumb mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:` is a part of the method name, so you need to do:

```
if ([answer respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {
```

And then use `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:`. The first is to access objects in the dictionary, the later is for the so-called Key-Value Coding. So it's:

```
id answer = [self.answers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([answer respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey:)]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [answer objectForKey:@"answer_id"];
} else {
    [NSException raise:@"Answer is of invalid class" format:@"It should be able to respond to objectForKey:, class: %@", [answer class]];
}
```

Last but not least, it looks like the object you get out of the `answer` dictionary is a `NSNumber`, not an `NSString`. So you might want to change the setting of the text to:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [[answer objectForKey:@"answer_id"] description];
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, stack overflow's api sends back a number.  That is to say that the value stored for the key `answer_id` is an `NSNumber` in the dictionary and not `NSString` and you should treat it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use: --

```
NSDictionary *answer = [self.answers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if ([answer respondsToSelector:@selector(objectForKey)]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [answer valueForKey:@"answer_id"];
} else {
    [NSException raise:@"Answer is of invalid class" format:@"It should be able to respond to valueForKey, class: %@", [answer class]];
}
```

**OR**

```
 id answer = [self.answers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (answer isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class])
{
  cell.textLabel.text = [answer valueForKey:@"answer_id"];
    } else {
        // I'm ending up here, instead of the cell.textLabel being set
        [NSException raise:@"Answer is of invalid class" format:@"It should be able to respond to valueForKey, class: %@", [answer class]];
    }
```

Comment: There are several problems with your proposed solutions: In your first solution you're testing for the wrong selector (`objectForKey` vs `objectForKey:`) and you're then using the wrong selector to actually get the object from the dictionary (`valueForKey` vs. `objectForKey:`). Your second version is slightly better but still uses `valueForKey:`. In neither of your solutions are you converting the NSNumber to a string.

Comment: yes .. it should be objectForKey: in both the cases everywhere .